# Array data is not uploading in mysql database - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

I have multiple records in the `$validData` array. I have printed the `$validData` record using `foreach` and `var_dump` just to show you its format. All I want to do is to store that `$validData` in the database but I'm not able to do that.

`$validData` is being populated using `forloop`. `$sheet` has valid data, don't worry about that. Below is the function inside the controller

```dart
public function import(Request $request)
{
foreach ($row_range as $rowID) {
            $name = $sheet->getCell('A' . $rowID)->getValue();
            $email = $sheet->getCell('B' . $rowID)->getValue();
            $contact = $sheet->getCell('C' . $rowID)->getValue();
            $address = $sheet->getCell('D' . $rowID)->getValue();
            $nutritionPlan_id = $sheet->getCell('E' . $rowID)->getValue();
            $company_id = $sheet->getCell('F' . $rowID)->getValue();
            $validData[] = [
                    'name' =>  $name,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'contact' =>  $contact,
                    'address' => $address,
                    'nutritionplan_id' => $nutritionPlan_id,
                    'company_id' => $company_id,
                ];
}

 echo "<br><br><b>Valid Data</b><br>";
 foreach ($validData as $key => $value) {
     echo ($value['name'] . "<br>" . $value['email'] . "<br><br> ");
 }
     var_dump($validData);
     // -------------------------
     $result = Customer::insert($validData); // <----- Trying to insert using this line.
     echo ("Insert result : " . $result);

 
      $result = Customer::create($validData); 
      echo ("Create result : " . $result);
     // -------------------------
```

**Result of** `Customer::insert($validData)`:

```dart
Insert result : 1
```

**Result of** `Customer::create($validData)`:

````
Insert result : {"updated_at":"2022-05-20T11:22:24.000000Z","created_at":"2022-05-20T11:22:24.000000Z","id":348}```
````

The customer model class looks like this

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $table = 'customers';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'email',
        'contact',
        'address',
        'nutritionplan_id',
        'company_id',
    ];
}
```

The database is also correctly connected in `.env`, I verified it by adding a new user.

**What I have tried?**

- Matched all the `$fillable` attributes as to the controller attributes names
- Added `'strict' => false,` in `mysql` array of `database.php`

I'm not sure what am I missing?

The output of the above echoes

[image]

**Edit**

`database\migrations\2022_05_13_124803_create_customers_table.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('contact');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->bigInteger('nutritionPlan_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('customers');
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the return value of the `insert()`?

Comment: Could you please share your table migration?

Comment: I don't get any error when I use insert but it also don't upload my data in db

Comment: @A.Seddighi I have edited the question and added migration file of `customers`

Comment: I mean I think the `insert()` returns the `bool`. is the return value false?

Comment: Also, could you please decrease the insert items of the array to one item and test with `insert()` return value

Comment: `<----- This throws error` - _what_ error?

Comment: @CBroe No it is also not throwing any error now. It was throwing one but now it disappeared

Comment: @A.Seddighi I have checked the `insert` result like this.,`echo ("Insert result " . $result);` and it is showing 1. I think it is false, right? `Insert result 1`

Comment: It's better to use `dump()`, `dd()` or logs for debug. echo is not certain. but I think it means true. something is wrong with the database. To check that, add a row manually to the database and check with Laravel to existence that

Comment: To check if the database is properly linked with the project. I created new user using authentication it was registered successfully

Comment: @A.Seddighi I have printed the result of both `insert` and `create` above

Answer (score 0):

It is your $validData correctly formatted? Here is an example to follow:

```
$data = [
    ['user_id'=>'Coder 1', 'subject_id'=> 4096],
    ['user_id'=>'Coder 2', 'subject_id'=> 2048],
    //...
];

Model::insert($data); // Eloquent approach
DB::table('table')->insert($data); // Query Builder approach
```

Check your dump($validData).

Another thing, make sure that your migration accepts null or has default value set where your have missing values in your $validData.

OR YOU CAN TRY A DIFFERENT METHOD:

```
public function import(Request $request)
{
foreach ($row_range as $rowID) {
            $name = $sheet->getCell('A' . $rowID)->getValue();
            $email = $sheet->getCell('B' . $rowID)->getValue();
            $contact = $sheet->getCell('C' . $rowID)->getValue();
            $address = $sheet->getCell('D' . $rowID)->getValue();
            $nutritionPlan_id = $sheet->getCell('E' . $rowID)->getValue();
            $company_id = $sheet->getCell('F' . $rowID)->getValue();

$customer = new Customer();
$customer->name = $name;
$customer->email = $email;
$customer->contact = $contact;
$customer->address = $naddressme;
$customer->nutritionPlan_id = $nutritionPlan_id;
$customer->company_id = $company_id;
$customer->save();
           
}
```

Comment: In the above screenshot of echo, the last part is the complete result of  `var_dump($validData)`.  You can see the data attributes of the `customer` model, in `migration` and in the valid data are the same. I'm also gonna share the screenshot of the MySQL database. So you can check, that attributes are also the same in the database.

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/GsQ3Jxd/Screenshot-2022-05-20-170431.jpg

Comment: I cannot follow the screenshot to well, hard to read. But I still can see that you pass empty values for "nutritionPlan_id" and "company_id"

Comment: yes you are right. Here is more readable `$validData` https://ctxt.io/2/AADgGn4CFg

Comment: So shouldn't be empty, Should I simply make them nullable?

Comment: As `$table->bigInteger('nutritionPlan_id')->unsigned(); $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();` are not nullable() or default('some value). Put some values on "nutritionPlan_id" and "company_id" and try again or make them `->nullable();`

Comment: I have edited both `company_id` and `nutritionpkan_id` as nullable like this `$table->bigInteger('nutritionPlan_id')->nullable();` inside `Schema::create` and ran `php artisan migrate --path=database\migrations\2022_05_13_124803_create_customers_table.php`

It is saying `Nothing to migrate.`

Comment: use `php artisan make:migration alter_table_customers --table=customers` to create a new migration for the changes only.  Edit that migration like: `

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('nutritionPlan_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->change();
            $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->change();
        });
    }
`

Comment: Wait I have just checked, when I print  `nutritionplan_id` and `company_id` separately in form loop it is not null but inside `var_dump` it is. Code: https://ctxt.io/2/AADgspQ7Fw
Result Image: https://ibb.co/0nzYYpr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244898/discussion-between-militaru-and-faizan-kamal).